# geopandas: how do I merge information only if point is inside a polygon?

Tags: python, pandas, shapefile, geopandas

I have a `geopandas` dataframe `A` with the geometry field set to a single `Point` (x,y). Then I have a second dataframe `B` with the geometry field set to some polygon and some other information. For example:

```
A 
geometry 
(1,2)
(3,4) 
...
```

and

```
B
info    polygon
ab      <some polygon>
bc      <some other polygon>
...     ...
```

How do I add a new column to `A` with `B`'s `info` field only if the point  in `A` is inside the polygon in `B`?

I would like to end up with something like

```
A
geometry    info
(1,2)       ab
(3,4)       ab
(7,9)       bc
...         ...
```

Comment: You should post some real data so we can try to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case someone else needs it, and assuming your geometry is well-formed, then you can do:

`new_df = gpd.sjoin(A,B,how="inner", op='intersects')`

this was enough.